# Add a custom tab alongside Screen Options and Help

Tags: screen-options

Using the `WP_Screen` object, is it possible to add additional tabs to a custom admin settings page?

I already have Screen Options and Help, but I also wish to add a Import/Export tab.  I've looked in to extending the `WP_Screen` object, but it's declared as `final` in the core (/wp-admin/includes/screen.php, line 194 {ver 4.2.1}).

I'd consider adding my import/export option to the Screen Options tab, but looking at `WP_Screen` object I can't see that even this is possible. **Edit** This is possible using the `screen_settings` filter, but I'd still like to achieve my primary goal if possible.

Comment: I *know*, we had exactly this question already.

Comment: And do you know where I can find that question, and if it has an accepted answer?  The closest I have found is a hack using JS from 2010, which I believe is pre-`WP_Screen` (in it's current format anyway).

Comment: Have you tried using add_help_tab()? https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Screen/add_help_tab

Comment: This is not possible with WordPress WP_Screen class right now, the tabs displayed are hard coded in `render_screen_options()` function of the same class. But you can use custom JS for this functionality.

Answer (score -2):

I changed my mind about "Most important: in the hook for validating updates, set-screen-option, pass the $value back if your plugin does not recognize the $option ! It's probably for another plugin!"

It's better to go with what the hook suggest and send back $status (which is false) if you don't know the $option.

To prevent conflicts with other plugins, instead I put in a $_GET['page'] check before adding the validator filter.